# list reverse, list multiple by -1

Tags: python

Expected Result:

```
>>> createLists(5)
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [ -5, -4, -3, -2, -1], [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5])
```

My code:

```
  # Write a function that returns 4 lists given a postive number.
    def createLists(num): 
        ls =    [item for item in range(num)]
        return set(ls, ls.reverse(), ls.reverse()*(-1), ls*(-1))
```

Anybody guide me how to do this?

Comment: It's good that you provided code, but you should also provide any incorrect results or errors that you're getting.

Comment: you should multiply every element of the list instead of the whole list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def createLists(num): 
    ls = range(1, num+1)
    return (ls, ls[::-1], [-n for n in ls][::-1], [-n for n in ls])

print createLists(5)
```

http://ideone.com/B0ixx

Comment: Or just `-n` instead of `-1*n`.

Comment: Just FYI, last two lists are swapped.

Comment: why you're using a list comprehension in the first line?

Answer (score 0):

The two problems you are running into are: 
1. reverse() reverses the list in place and returns nothing, so `set(ls, ls.reverse())` is like calling `set(ls, None)` 
2. set expects one list or other iterable, not several scalar arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost doing it right, except that multiplying a list by negative number will not make each element negative but it will become an empty list. Instead you should write a simple function to make each element negative or multiply by some number e.g.

```
def listmul(items, multiplier):
    return [item*multiplier for item in items]

print listmul(range(5), -1)
```

output:

```
[0, -1, -2, -3, -4]
```